# Passing description from browser in elsa

Tags: elsa-workflows

In document workflow, after I reject/approve the document in the mail, I want it to take to the browser where I can add a comment in the comment box and then pass that comment back to the employee through email. How can it be done?

I have tried adding comments in console and pass it through mail.How can it be done in UI designer?

Comment: You can create a page containing the fields you want and send the URL of this page in the first email and then post that page data back to the elsa using an HTTP request.

Comment: Hi, if you don't mind can you please give some idea on how to create a custom web page

Comment: I meant creating a web page in your project not adding anything to Elsa, just add a page as you do it like any other page and use Elsa to handle the flow.

Comment: Have you tried with any poc? If yes, can you please share the same?

Answer (score 1):

@vahidnaderi is spot-on:

1. In the workflow from where you send the email containing the approve/reject link(s), have these links point to a custom webpage you create.
2. This webpage contains 3 fields and a submit button:

   1. A  radiolist with an "approve" and "reject" radiobuttons
   2. A "comments" textarea.
   3. A "workflowinstanceid" hidden field that stores the workflow instance ID.
3. When the form is submitted to your backend application, you trigger a signal ("approve" or "reject") for the appropriate workflow instance ID and provide the comment as input.
4. Your workflow will resume and the received comment will be available as input to the first activity that comes after the "signal received" activity.
5. That activity should either be the "send email" activity or a "set variable" activity in case you want access to the received comment later in the workflow.
6. From the "send email" activity, you can now access the comment you wish to include with the email.

Obviously, you're completely free to do things differently. For example, perhaps you want a separate page for "approve" and another page for "reject".

The key takeaway here is that you provide your own web UI. This web UI then interacts with your application backend (i.e. by submitting a form to a controller), which then interacts with Elsa services to e.g. trigger workflows.